# change the content of py file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python file which contain a dictionary and one more file which importing the file with the dictionary.
I need to change the actual value of keys, I mean permanently - not by importing and editing for the code, 
How can I accomplish that ?

Comment: By changing the values in the file that contains the dictionary?

Comment: If the data needs to be editable, you should store it in a data-friendly format; JSON, YAML, Python pickle perhaps. Then load the file, edit the data, serialise it into a file again.

Comment: Source code *is not data* and you should keep the two separate.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good reason why programmers have learned over the years not to modify the source of their programs under program control. It results in a mess, particularly when multiple people try to use the same program at the same time, and means that you can't effectively keep your code under source control.

It would be much better to use some way of storing the keys and values outside the program. Depending on the types of key that could be a shelve, a relational database or a number of other things. If it varies, data should not be built into your program's source.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

```
import pickle

myDict = {"foo": "bar", "spam": "eggs"}
pickle.dump(myDict, "myFile.py") # Stores object in a file

dictFromFile = pickle.load("myFile.py") # Retrieves object from files
print dictFromFile["spam"] # Prints eggs
```